# Changing to custom font xaml (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, fonts

I have the ttf in a folder called Font and I'm trying to set the text to the font using

```
FontFamily="Font/compctab.ttf#Compacta Bd Bt"
```

On my other project it worked and on this one its not changing here is what I have on my project that works

```
FontFamily="Fonts/ninjanaruto.ttf#Ninja Naruto"
```

I even put that ttf in the folder and copied the code, but its still not working...

Comment: You may check ttf file is part of the project and has the same build ation

Answer (score 0):

you need to use expression blend and add the phone using Font Manager. This then sets the font as BlendResource and can then be used

See the post before for step by step instructions

http://www.markarteaga.com/custom-fonts-in-windows-phone-7-with-expression-blend/