# Font Manager missing in Blend for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: xaml, fonts, visual-studio-2015, blend

I'm trying to use a custom font ([Roboto by Google](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto#charset)) in a clients Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT, not Silverlight) app. [Following this tutorial](http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/01/04/a-complete-guide-to-working-with-custom-fonts-in-your-windows-and-windows-phone-app) I have included the .ttf and set the "Build Action" to "Content" - unfortunately, this does not work.

[This answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048059/changing-to-custom-font-xaml-windows-phone) I should use the Font Manager in Blend to embed the font, unfortunately I can't seem to find that tool in the latest version (Blend for Visual Studio 2015). Has this feature been moved / removed?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. Are you looking for the font manager as well or having trouble with this specific font?

Comment: Yeah I cannot find it either :(